# LgCeil - My professor says my code does not work for 1<n<=4

Tags: python

Directions:

> The binary logarithm of a positive number `y`, `lg y`, is the exponent
>   `x` such that `y == 2 ** x`. For example, `lg 8 = 3` since `8 == 2 ** 3`,
>   `lg(1024) = 10` since `1024 == 2 ** 10`, `lg(1025) ≈ 10.0014` and
>   `lg(2013.15) ≈ 10.9752`.
>
> Implement `lgCeil(x)`, which returns the ceiling of the binary log of
>   `x` for `x ≥ 1`. DO NOT import the `math` module. Instead, use a
>   `while` loop. `lgCeil(8)` returns `3`; `lgCeil(1024)` returns `10`,
>   `lgCeil(1025)` and `lgCeil(2013.15)` both return `11`.

My code:

```
def lgCeil(x):
    startNum = 0
    numOfTimes = 0
    base = 2
    integer = base * 2
    while not(integer >= x):
        startNum = 2
        numOfTimes = numOfTimes + 1
        integer = integer * base
    numOfTimes = numOfTimes + startNum
    if (integer <= x):
        base**(numOfTimes+1)
    return numOfTimes

print (lgCeil(8))
print (lgCeil(1024))
print (lgCeil(1025))
print (lgCeil(2013.15))
print (lgCeil(4))
```

I'm not sure what I need to fix.

Comment: have you verified what the professor said?

Comment: What values does your code give between 1 and 4? What values were you expecting?

Comment: But, just looking at your code, your minimum return value is `3` for anything that makes it into that while loop. So yeah, it's definitely wrong for values <= 4. You're also repeatedly setting `startNum` to `2` inside the loop for some reason (and that's why you always return 3 or greater... I'm not really sure what this number is supposed to be, you never use it in math).

Comment: There's http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for questions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *much* simpler than you're making it - you have roughly the right implementation (increase a number until you equal or exceed the input), but there's a lot of complexity that breaks things.

```
def lgCeil(x):
    startNum = 0
    numOfTimes = 0 # why two values to keep count?
    base = 2
    integer = base * 2 # what about numbers <= 2?
    while not(integer >= x): # why not 'integer < x'?
        startNum = 2 # always resets to 2 - why?
        numOfTimes = numOfTimes + 1 # could just be '+= 1'
        integer = integer * base # could just be '*= base'
    numOfTimes = numOfTimes + startNum # always adding on a fixed 2
    if (integer <= x):
        base**(numOfTimes+1) # this line doesn't actually contribute to output
    return numOfTimes
```

Consider this much simpler implementation:

```
def log_ceil(num, base=2):
    """Calculate the 'ceiling log' for the specified number."""
    val = 0
    while (base ** val) < num:
        val += 1
    return val
```

This is also compliant with the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: This helped so much! I knew what I was doing was a little too much more complicated

Answer (score 1):

You should go down to zero with the value instead of going up. 
I wrote a working sample, but it uses shifting so your prof is most likely you did not write it. You should not simply copy it! Try to understand and reproduce it!

```
# This is not Java, functions are lowercase with underscore.
def lg_ceil(value):
    '''
    calculate the n for 2^n <= value < 2^(n + 1) with a while loop (actually a bad idea)
    '''
    # make sure we have an int
    value = int(value)
    # not defined for values <= 1
    if value <= 1:
        return
    result = 0

    # as long as value != 0
    while value:
        # shift value one bit, this equals / 2 with integers.
        value = value >> 1
        # count the numbers of shifts
        result += 1
    # the result is the number shifts minus 1.
    return result - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lgCeil(x):
    numOfTimes = 0
    base=2
    integer = 2
    while not(integer >= x):
        numOfTimes = numOfTimes + 1
        integer = integer * base
    return numOfTimes+1
```

Answer (score 1):

As jonrsharpe indicates, your code with a minimum of correction would look like this:

```
def lgCeil(x):  
    if (x <= 1):
        return 0    

    startNum = 0    
    numOfTimes = 0  
    base = 2    
    integer = base * 1  

    while not(integer >= x):    
        startNum = 0    
        numOfTimes = numOfTimes + 1 
        integer = integer * base    

    numOfTimes = numOfTimes + startNum  

    if (integer <= x):  
        base**(numOfTimes+1)    

    return numOfTimes+1 


print (lgCeil(1))   
print (lgCeil(1.1)) 
print (lgCeil(2))   
print (lgCeil(2.1)) 
print (lgCeil(4))   
print (lgCeil(4.1)) 
print (lgCeil(8))   
print (lgCeil(1024))    
print (lgCeil(1025))    
print (lgCeil(2013.15))
```

Though I added the exception (Klaus D. also mentions) regarding x=1 (actually for 0 < x <= 1)

This was just to sum up if you are not going for a completely new version.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner:

```
In [7]: len(bin(int(2013.15)).strip("0b"))
Out[7]: 11
```

Tweak needed to support exact powers, e.g. 1024, is left as an exercise to the reader.